# PowerBI: ALL() deja de funcionar si ordeno una columna en función de otra

Tags: powerbi, dax

A partir de una columna con el año, que a día de hoy va de 1980 a 2009 -aunque en un futuro empezará en 1960-, he creado otras dos con la década, una de tipo entero y otra de tipo texto:

```
decada = CONCATENATE(MID(listas_spotify[ano], 1, 3), 0)
decada_texto = CONCATENATE(MID(listas_spotify[ano], 3, 1), "0s")
```

PowerBI ordena `decada_texto` tal que "00s -> 80s -> 90s", por lo que la he "enganchado" a `decada`, que al ser un entero no sufre de este tipo de problemas, para que el orden sea "80s -> 90s -> 00s":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bien, el problema es que al hacer esto surge un problema con `ALL()`; si hacemos un recuento del número de décadas distintas que existen y le decimos que no tenga en cuenta el contexto de filtro para la propia `decada_texto`:

```
decadas = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(listas_spotify[decada_texto]), ALL(listas_spotify[decada_texto]))
```

Éste es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`ALL()` no surte efecto.

Si desengancho `decada_texto` de `decada` (observad que el orden vuelve a ser "00s -> 80s -> 90s"):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`ALL()` vuelve a funcionar con normalidad.

¿Qué manera hay de solucionar esto manteniendo el orden que yo quiero?

Comment: No se me ocuure una solución para esto. Yo de primeras pondría las columnas de las décadas en Power Query, de manera que Power BI no las tome como columnas calculadas, sospechando que pueda tener un bug.

Comment: Creándolas desde Power Query ocurre lo mismo. En cuanto se ordena `decada_texto` según `decada`, `ALL()` deja de funcionar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es añadir un segundo `ALL()` que haga referencia a la columna que se toma como referencia para la ordenación:

```
decadas = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(listas_spotify[decada_texto]), ALL(listas_spotify[decada_texto]), ALL(listas_spotify[decada]))
```